# SSH issues on GCP VM migrated from AWS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have migrated an EC2 instance (amazon linux) to Google cloud (ubuntu 18.04) using cloud endure.
But I am not able to ssh into google cloud VM. I dont have EC2 instance anymore. How can I access the Google cloud VM ? Error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]
```

Answer (score 0):

using gcloud command you can config your SSH

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
```

for more details on config-ssh  ref :
 [Link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh)

Comment: Tried this. N0 success. Keep getting Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: there is issue with  key in  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys , 
you can do serial port login in machine to see more details and log

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Answer (score 0):

If the `gcloud compute config-ssh` doesn't work check the [firewall rules for your machine](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls); **find the VPC it's in and make sure port 22 is open - it may happen it's blocked**.

If you're not sure if SSH can come through [create a rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-firewall-rules) for it.

Very similar issue was also discussed in [this topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193535/error-gcloud-compute-ssh-usr-bin-ssh-exited-with-return-code-255) which might help you.

You can (to be absolutely sure SSH traffic is allowed to your VM) set up a startup script for it: edit the VM in question and find "Custom Metadata" section and click "Add Item", next type `startup-script` as a key and the command `sudo ufw allow ssh` in the "value" field.

Having the SSH traffic enabled in the GCP firewall and the VM itself you should be able to log in.