# google cloud change sudo password

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I cannot login in my google cloud vm using gcloud cli, but I found a work around here: [ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193535/error-gcloud-compute-ssh-usr-bin-ssh-exited-with-return-code-255/55265385#55265385) 
So I created a new user as the post said, logged in my vm successfully with that user. Now I want to switch to root user - So I Use `su -`, but it requires a password, which i don't have. How can i switch to root?

Comment: To switch to the root user without entering a password `sudo bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The answer is surprisingly easy, just use `sudo passwd` and it will allow you set a new password without current one.