# Cant connect to VM using ssh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have tried so many things, disabling OS login, creating a new ssh key (which didnt allow me to connect since it asked for a login and password, which I didnt have), resized the disk, all of those things and nothing has worked. I would really appreciate ANY help, I feel like im going insane.

When I try to connect using gcloud compute ssh, it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) \[/usr/bin/ssh\] exited with return code \[255\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193535/error-gcloud-compute-ssh-usr-bin-ssh-exited-with-return-code-255)

Comment: When posting your question, what makes your question different from the zillion other ones with the same problem? Then show the steps you used to try and solve the problem. Start by searching Stack Overflow and Google Cloud's website for debugging guides. Show those steps in your question. Otherwise, we can only guess what the real problem/solution is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, you should try changing the name of the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to check if you instance start up with working guest environments. If not you have to install the guest environments by some steps. There is very detail steps provided by Google.

**Validate Guest Environment**

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei_console_logs

**Installing the guest environment**

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment

It works for me, hope works for you too.
(P.S. I hit the problem after upgraded OS version)